# Prove that if $n$ is odd and $p \mid n$, then $\sum_{m=1,\, \gcd(m,n)=1}^{\varphi(n)} (\frac{m}{p})=0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, quadratic-residues

I have to prove this statement for my class, but I have run into an issue. When I choose $n=15$, for example, and if I choose $p=3$, I get
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq m \leq 8 \\[1pt] \gcd(m,15)=1}} 
\biggl(\frac{m}{3\strut}\biggr) 
&= \biggl(\frac{1}{3\strut}\biggr) 
+ \biggl(\frac{2}{3\strut}\biggr) 
+ \biggl(\frac{4}{3\strut}\biggr) 
+ \biggl(\frac{7}{3\strut}\biggr) 
+ \biggl(\frac{8}{3\strut}\biggr) \\ 
&= 1 - 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 = 1
\end{align}
not $0$. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: $\varphi(15)=8$.  The classes are $\{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\}$.  Your sum should cover all the classes prime to $n$...not stop at $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: I don't really understand why it should not stop at 8 if the upper limit of the summation is φ(n), which is 8 in this case.

Comment: Well, that's wrong,  as your example shows.  Try it with the sum over all the relevant classes.

Comment: Perhaps whoever wrote this originally intended there to be an index.  After all, it's sheer coincidence that $\gcd(\varphi(15), 15)=1$.  No reason for that, generally.  Maybe they meant to introduce a set of representatives $\{m_i\}_{i=1}^{\varphi(n)}$ and then write the sum as $\sum_{i=1}^{\varphi(n)} \left(\frac {m_i}p\right)$.  That would make sense.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It makes more sense your way.